# Python's modulo misunderstanding

Tags: python, datetime, modulo

I've got that code and I don't think that I really understand how the modulo returns the remainder, not good at maths..

Here is the code:

```
#import the datetime class
import datetime

#declare and initialize variables
strDeadline = ""
totalNbrDays = 0
nbrWeeks = 0
nbrDays = 0

#Get Today's date
currentDate = datetime.date.today()

#Ask the user for the date of their deadline
strDeadline = input("Please enter the date of your deadline (mm/dd/yyyy): ")

deadline = datetime.datetime.strptime(strDeadline,"%m/%d/%Y").date()

#Calculate number of days between the two dates
totalNbrDays = deadline - currentDate

#For extra credit calculate results in weeks & days

nbrWeeks = totalNbrDays.days / 7

#The modulo will return the remainder of the division
#which will tell us how many days are left 
nbrDays = totalNbrDays.days%7

#display the result to the user

print("You have %d weeks" %nbrWeeks + " and %d days " %nbrDays + "until your deadline.")
```

Comment: What is your question, what is the expected result of your code and what is the actual result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you divide an integer by another integer, it doesn't always go in evenly. For example, `23 / 7` will give you a remainder of `2` because `23 = 7 * 3 + 2`. Modulo gives you the remainder of a division operation... `23 % 7 = 2`. This is useful when you have a number of days that is longer than a week's worth of time. You can use integer division (meaning the quotient will be a whole number) to calculate the number of weeks `23 / 7 = 3` and then modulo to calculate the number of days left over `23 % 7 = 2`, telling you that 23 days is equal to 3 weeks and 2 days.

Answer (score 2):

The modulo is used to take the remainder of the expression.

For example, when you do 15%7, you get 1. This is because 7+7+1=15.

In your code you take the total amount of days (totalNbrDays.days) and divide it by the amount of days in a week(7). Lets use an example of 30 for the total number of days. 30%7 would be equal to 2 because 7+7+7+7+2=30, or (7*4)=28 and 30-28=2.